# Setting form method to get without specifying controller and action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a partial view which I need to re-use:

```
div class="selectDate">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewTransactionLog", "Profile", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="selectDateLabel">Date:</div>
    <div>
    @Html.TextBox("start", range.Start, new { @class = "pickDate" }) to @Html.TextBox("end", range.End, new { @class = "pickDate" })

    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </div>
}
</div>
```

This is the code for picking 2 dates. As the data is lightweight, I wish to pass it through the Get method. I also wish to generalize it and put it into its own cshtml; however, `Html.BeginForm` expects the controller name and action name to be given if I wish to use the Get method. Is there anyway to avoid this so I could just move the code into a partial view of its own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the form to post back to the current controller and action, you should be able to use an extension method:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm<TModel>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
    FormMethod formMethod)
{
    string controller = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
    string action = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

    return html.BeginForm(action, controller, formMethod);
}
```